# How do I input a specific folder ID into a Google Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to run a simple script to move files from one folder to another, but I'm not sure how to input the folders into the script.

I'm trying to use [this code I found](https://ctrlq.org/code/19975-move-file-between-folders) so that I can set up a trigger on script.google.com and have the files move automatically.

So I enter:

```
var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("###redacted###")

var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("###redacted###")

function moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder) {

  var files = source_folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    dest_folder.addFile(file);
    source_folder.removeFile(file);

  }
}
```

But when I hit "Run," I see this error: `TypeError: Cannot call method "getFiles" of undefined. (line 7, file "Code")`

I don't understand what syntax to use to actually specify what the `source_folder` and `dest_folder` should be. The goal is just to specify the Google Drive folders in the script, and then to set up a trigger so that the files will just move automatically every few hours or so.

How do I actually specify the folders for the script so that the script will be able to run properly?

Comment: If you want to give ``source_folder`` and ``dest_folder`` using the folder ID, how about using ``DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)``? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid In your script, when ``source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId)`` and ``dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId)`` are used, the files in the source folder can be moved to the destination folder.

Comment: Sorry, I'm brand new to this.

So if I add these two lines to the top of the script:

`var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)`

`var dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)` I'm still getting an error when I try to run it: `Missing ) after argument list. (line 1, file "Code")`

Comment: Thank you for replying. It is considered that the error is due to the syntax error. So can you add your latest script for replicating the issue to your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Just edited to add what I'm trying.

Comment: Are you missing quotes around the "`id`" ?

Comment: Good call, but now I'm running into more errors. Will update.

Comment: Updated for new error message

Comment: @user260467 If you want to use ``source_folder`` and ``dest_folder`` as the global variables, please modify from ``function moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder) {`` to ``function moveFiles() {``. Because when ``function moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder) {`` is used, both variables are replaced to ``undefined``.

Comment: This was perfect. If you want to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @user260467 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I posted an answer by including the explanation. And I think that this situation might be also useful for other users. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to retrieve `folder` object from folder ID, please use `DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)

The reason of the error of `TypeError: Cannot call method "getFiles" of undefined. (line 7, file "Code")` is due to `source_folder` and `dest_folder` of `function moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder) {}`.

In this case, when the function of `moveFiles` is run, because `source_folder` and `dest_folder` are not given, those values are replaced to `undefined`. By this, such error occurs. In order to use `source_folder` and `dest_folder` as the global variables and avoid this error, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
function moveFiles(source_folder, dest_folder) {
```

#### To:

```
function moveFiles() {
```